# How to change browser search engine by javaScript or another logic

Tags: javascript, browser

In my application I have to give one option for setting my current web application as default search engine for browser.

can same common function work for all browser ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change search engine from web page. You can only detect user browser and provide search engine change instruction depending on browser.

Comment: So if browser is chrome, so how can i set default search engine?

Comment: chrome://settings/searchEngines

Comment: I mean through logic how can i change setting, not with manually.

Comment: You can't, fortunately. Otherwise, Websites would frequently change ***your*** search engine without your permission.